# JTextArea как убрать пустую строку

Tags: java, строки, swing

Есть ли противоположный по действию символ `\n` (перевод строки)?
Мне нужно в `JTextArea` удалить выделенную строку, но после удаления этой строки следующая строка, которая выводится в `JTextArea`, идет как бы через одну строку. Т.е. по сути мне нужно добавить после каждого удаления строки "Backspace". Как это сделать?

Код для удаления строки:

```java
delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        t2.setText(t2.getText().replace(t2.getSelectedText(), "")); 
    }
});
```

Comment: delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                t2.setText(t2.getText().replace(t2.getSelectedText(),""));
            }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема НЕ воспроизводится в том виде, как описана.

Чтобы удалить выделенную строку в `JTextArea`, нужно её выделить **правильно**.

Если текст выделяется *до конца текущей строки* (при помощи мышки или клавиш <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>), при этом НЕ будет захвачен символ перевода строки `\n`, соответственно, он и не может быть удалён.

В этом легко убедиться, если залогировать состояние текста:

```java
this.btnDelete.addActionListener(e -> {
    String selected = txt.getSelectedText();
    System.out.println("Selected: [" + selected + "], ends with \\n? " + selected.endsWith("\n"));
    txt.setText(txt.getText().replace(selected, ""));
});
```

```
Selected: [bbb], ends with \n? false
```

Но если строка или несколько строк выделены **с захватом** символа `'\n'`, например, при помощи <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>, они будут удалены корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Selected: [
ccc
], ends with \n? true
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Разумеется, можно исправить код, чтобы захватывать дополнительно ещё один символ при удалении, но это будет нестандартное поведение для пользователя.

Также для удаления текста следует использовать метод [`JTextComponent::replaceSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#replaceSelection-java.lang.String-), так как при использовании метода [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) будут заменяться *все* подходящие строки, например, могут быть удалены *все* переводы строки `'\n'`.

```java
this.btnDelete.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (txt.getSelectionEnd() < txt.getText().length() && txt.getText().charAt(txt.getSelectionEnd()) == '\n') {
        txt.setSelectionEnd(txt.getSelectionEnd() + 1);
    }
    String selected = txt.getSelectedText();

    System.out.println("Selected: [" + selected + "], ends with \\n? " + selected.endsWith("\n"));
    txt.replaceSelection("");
});
```

```
Selected: [wwww
], ends with \n? true
Selected: [
yyyy
], ends with \n? true
Selected: [xxxx], ends with \n? false
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, нужно будет почаще читать документацию :)